Spring boot war is deploying on Wildfly 26 but application is not starting
I have a Spring Boot application packaged as a WAR file and deployed on a server with WildFly 26.1.6. The deployment seems to work correctly because I see no errors in the WildFly logs, and I can access a static resource like index.html.
For example:
http://moon:28080/reportplanner/index.html works fine and shows the content.
However, when I try to access my REST endpoints (e.g., /api/task/all), I always get a 404 Not Found error.
Project Configuration:
Spring Boot Version: 3.4.0
WildFly Version: 26.1.6.Final
Main class:
package com.reportplanner;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@Slf4j
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.reportplanner.domain")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.reportplanner.repository")
public class ReportPlannerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println("Report Planner application starting...");
        log.info("Report Planner application starting...");
        SpringApplication.run(ReportPlannerApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(ReportPlannerApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Report Planner application started Successfully!");
    }
}

application.properties:
spring.application.name=ReportPlanner
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
logging.level.com=INFO

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.reportplanner</groupId>
    <artifactId>ReportPlanner</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ReportPlanner</name>
    <description>Report Planner Web Application: Backend Service</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.18.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-client-all</artifactId>
            <version>26.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>reportplanner</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


What I've Tried:
I verified the @RequestMapping and @RestController annotations are correct.
The same WAR file works perfectly when run with an embedded Tomcat server in localhost.
I checked the WildFly logs for errors and found no issues during deployment.
Wildfly server.log:
11:32:15,506 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-2)  VM Arguments: -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Dresteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB=true -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\dump-20241220-1132.hprof -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.siveco.prop.skipTimeZoneConversion=true -Dcom.siveco.prop.disableUploadManagement=true -Djbo.passivationstore=file -Djbo.tmpdir=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\siveco\ampool -Djbo.dofailover=false -Djbo.ampool.doampooling=true -Djbo.doconnectionpooling=false -Djbo.txn.disconnect_level=1 -Djbo.ampool.initpoolsize=0 -Djbo.ampool.maxpoolsize=120 -Djbo.recyclethreshold=120 -Djbo.ampool.maxinactiveage=600000 -Djbo.ampool.monitorsleepinterval=600000 -Djbo.ampool.timetolive=-1 -Djbo.ampool.maxavailablesize=120 -Djbo.ampool.minavailablesize=96 -Djbo.initpoolsize=0 -Djbo.poolmaxavailablesize=120 -Djbo.poolminavailablesize=96 -Dorg.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.port=50118 -Djboss.bind.address=172.16.66.3 -Djboss.httpPort=28080 -Djavamelody.disabled=true -Doracle.adfm.usemds=false -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -Dcom.siveco.jsf.JSFPanelBuilderXY.debug_layout=false -Djackrabbit.home=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\siveco\Jackrabbit -Djboss.home.dir=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final -Djboss.server.config.dir=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration -Djava.home.dir=C:/Coswin812sqldev/jdk-17.0.8+7 -Dcoswin.home.dir=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone -Dcoswin.reports= -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration\jaas-siveco-login-modules.conf -Doracle.mds.cache=simple -Djavamelody.storage-directory=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\siveco\javamelody -Dbusinessobjects.logs.home=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\businessobjects -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\tmp --illegal-access=deny --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=ALL-UNNAMED -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:ConcGCThreads=2 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70 -Xlog:gc*,gc+ref=debug,gc+heap=debug,gc+age=trace:file=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\gc-20241220-1132.log:tags,uptime,time,level:filecount=10,filesize=50m -Xlog:safepoint*:file=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\safepoints-20241220-1132.log:tags,uptime,time,level:filecount=10,filesize=50m --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.url.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.url.ldaps=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/javax.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming=ALL-UNNAMED -Djava.security.manager=allow -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration/logging.properties 
11:50:16,844 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-2)  Configured system properties:
    businessobjects.logs.home = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\businessobjects
    com.siveco.jsf.JSFPanelBuilderXY.debug_layout = false
    com.siveco.prop.disableUploadManagement = true
    com.siveco.prop.skipTimeZoneConversion = true
    coswin.home.dir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone
    coswin.reports = 
    file.encoding = Cp1252
    file.separator = \
    jackrabbit.home = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\siveco\Jackrabbit
    java.awt.headless = true
    java.class.path = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 61.0
    java.home = C:\Coswin812sqldev\jdk-17.0.8+7
    java.home.dir = C:/Coswin812sqldev/jdk-17.0.8+7
    java.io.tmpdir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\tmp
    java.library.path = C:\Coswin812sqldev\jdk-17.0.8+7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\app\AdminPC_tci\product\12.1.0\client_1;C:\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\sqlanywhere\BIN64;C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\sqlanywhere\BIN32;C:\app\instantclient_19_13;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\SMO\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.
    java.locale.providers = COMPAT
    java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
    java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 17.0.8+7
    java.security.auth.login.config = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration\jaas-siveco-login-modules.conf
    java.security.manager = allow
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 17
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Eclipse Adoptium
    java.vendor.url = https://adoptium.net/
    java.vendor.url.bug = https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
    java.vendor.version = Temurin-17.0.8+7
    java.version = 17.0.8
    java.version.date = 2023-07-18
    java.vm.compressedOopsMode = 32-bit
    java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
    java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 17
    java.vm.vendor = Eclipse Adoptium
    java.vm.version = 17.0.8+7
    javamelody.disabled = true
    javamelody.storage-directory = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\siveco\javamelody
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    jbo.ampool.doampooling = true
    jbo.ampool.initpoolsize = 0
    jbo.ampool.maxavailablesize = 120
    jbo.ampool.maxinactiveage = 600000
    jbo.ampool.maxpoolsize = 120
    jbo.ampool.minavailablesize = 96
    jbo.ampool.monitorsleepinterval = 600000
    jbo.ampool.timetolive = -1
    jbo.doconnectionpooling = false
    jbo.dofailover = false
    jbo.initpoolsize = 0
    jbo.passivationstore = file
    jbo.poolmaxavailablesize = 120
    jbo.poolminavailablesize = 96
    jbo.recyclethreshold = 120
    jbo.tmpdir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\siveco\ampool
    jbo.txn.disconnect_level = 1
    jboss.bind.address = 172.16.66.3
    jboss.home.dir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final
    jboss.host.name = moon
    jboss.httpPort = 28080
    jboss.modules.dir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\modules
    jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
    jboss.node.name = moon
    jboss.qualified.host.name = moon
    jboss.server.base.dir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone
    jboss.server.config.dir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\data
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\data\content
    jboss.server.log.dir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log
    jboss.server.name = moon
    jboss.server.persist.config = true
    jboss.server.temp.dir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\tmp
    jdk.debug = release
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration/logging.properties
    module.path = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\modules
    native.encoding = Cp1252
    oracle.adfm.usemds = false
    oracle.mds.cache = simple
    org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.port = 50118
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\server.log
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Windows Server 2019
    os.version = 10.0
    path.separator = ;
    program.name = standalone.bat
    resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB = true
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.library.path = C:\Coswin812sqldev\jdk-17.0.8+7\bin
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\jboss-modules.jar -secmgr -mp C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
    sun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax = true
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = 
    sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval = 3600000
    sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval = 3600000
    sun.stderr.encoding = cp850
    sun.stdout.encoding = cp850
    user.country = US
    user.country.format = IT
    user.dir = C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\bin
    user.home = C:\Users\SMO
    user.language = en
    user.language.format = it
    user.name = SMO
    user.script = 
    user.timezone = Europe/Rome
    user.variant = 
11:50:16,844 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-2)  VM Arguments: -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Dresteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB=true -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\dump-20241220-1150.hprof -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.siveco.prop.skipTimeZoneConversion=true -Dcom.siveco.prop.disableUploadManagement=true -Djbo.passivationstore=file -Djbo.tmpdir=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\siveco\ampool -Djbo.dofailover=false -Djbo.ampool.doampooling=true -Djbo.doconnectionpooling=false -Djbo.txn.disconnect_level=1 -Djbo.ampool.initpoolsize=0 -Djbo.ampool.maxpoolsize=120 -Djbo.recyclethreshold=120 -Djbo.ampool.maxinactiveage=600000 -Djbo.ampool.monitorsleepinterval=600000 -Djbo.ampool.timetolive=-1 -Djbo.ampool.maxavailablesize=120 -Djbo.ampool.minavailablesize=96 -Djbo.initpoolsize=0 -Djbo.poolmaxavailablesize=120 -Djbo.poolminavailablesize=96 -Dorg.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.port=50118 -Djboss.bind.address=172.16.66.3 -Djboss.httpPort=28080 -Djavamelody.disabled=true -Doracle.adfm.usemds=false -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -Dcom.siveco.jsf.JSFPanelBuilderXY.debug_layout=false -Djackrabbit.home=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\siveco\Jackrabbit -Djboss.home.dir=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final -Djboss.server.config.dir=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration -Djava.home.dir=C:/Coswin812sqldev/jdk-17.0.8+7 -Dcoswin.home.dir=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone -Dcoswin.reports= -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration\jaas-siveco-login-modules.conf -Doracle.mds.cache=simple -Djavamelody.storage-directory=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\siveco\javamelody -Dbusinessobjects.logs.home=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\businessobjects -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\tmp --illegal-access=deny --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=ALL-UNNAMED -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:ConcGCThreads=2 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70 -Xlog:gc*,gc+ref=debug,gc+heap=debug,gc+age=trace:file=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\gc-20241220-1150.log:tags,uptime,time,level:filecount=10,filesize=50m -Xlog:safepoint*:file=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\safepoints-20241220-1150.log:tags,uptime,time,level:filecount=10,filesize=50m --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.url.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.url.ldaps=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/javax.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming=ALL-UNNAMED -Djava.security.manager=allow -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\log\server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\Coswin812sqldev\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration/logging.properties 


You should show the log(the part with starting the context) from wildfly, too. Missing messages(' i.e. "Report Planner application starting...") can be as bad as erros...

I shared server.log, but as I said there is nothing there. That's how I'm supposing main application is not starting and endpoints are returning 404.

Seems Wildfly doesn't attempt to deploy anything. Maybe this helps:  https://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/spring/spring-boot-hello-world-on-wildfly/

Didn't help. Wildfly is deploying WARs but I can't reach endpoints.
